# Adding Simperium Module to Project gives Gradle DSL method not found: 'gitVersion()' error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, simperium, android-studio-import

I get an error after adding a `Simperium` Module Application code to my application. It gives me `Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'gitVersion()'` error. How can I fix it?

build.gradle code here:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sdn.com.sd"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':SDUtils')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile project(':SDAnalytics')
    compile project(':SDEditor')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile project(':SDNetworking')
    compile project(':PassCode')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-3.0.0-beta1.jar')
    compile project(':Simperium')
}
```

Gradle Sync message output:

```
Error:(13, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'gitVersion()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'SD' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: Post the build.gradle inside the Simperium module

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you can have the look of the Simperium module project at this link.
https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-android 
I had simply added this project as a module in my application

Comment: Check the answer below. You are missing some functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a module in your project (as you've explained in your comment)

> you can have the look of the Simperium module project at this link.  github.com/Simperium/simperium-android I had simply added this project as a module in my application

Gradle is trying to process the `build.gradle` inside the **Simperium module**.

https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-android/blob/develop/build.gradle

Inside this file there are some functions defined in the `root/build.gradle` of the Simperium-project.

```
def gitHash() {..}
def gitDescribe() {..}
def gitVersion(){..}
```

**You have to copy these functions** inside **your top-level** `build.gradle` file.

```
root
|--app
|----build.gradle
|--build.gradle   <- here
|--settings.gradle
```

Comment: Top level build.gradle file means the build.gradle file of my app or of my Project? Sorry as I am new to Studio hence having such queries.

Comment: Thanks Gabriele Sir, It worked like a gem. Thanks once again.

Comment: could you please also help me for some another question related to Android-Studio. Here is the link for the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544456/merged-rootschanged-not-allowed-inside-rootschanged-rootschanged-level-1 Thanks in advance.