# Merged rootsChanged not allowed inside rootsChanged, rootsChanged level == 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

On `Gradle sync` of my Android application in Android Studio my `Event Logs` shows me the Following Error:

```
Throwable:Merged rootsChanged not allowed inside rootsChanged, rootsChanged level == 1
```

But I don't know what is it for and how to resolve it. I had searched for it but didn't find anything relevant to it.

Can anybody can help me for the same?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seems related to some change in your modules. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183881 Try to delete the .idea folder and the .iml files and import again with gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti You are a true Gem, Please put it in the answer and I shall Accept it. Thanks once again Gabriele Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems related to some change in your modules.
Check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183881

Do the follow steps:

- delete the `.idea` folder
- delete the `.iml` files
- import again with gradle